# What's faster ? if()return;else return; OR if()return; return;

Tags: php, if-statement

While coding, i just asked myself this question :

Is this faster :

```
if(false) return true;
 else return false;
```

Than this ?

```
if(false) return true;
return false;
```

Of course, IF there is a difference it is ridiculous, but my curiosity won't leave until i know that :D

Comment: Did you try xdebug? And why do you think it's an important performance bottleneck? :| Btw, both lack in readability.

Comment: Measure it. A proper accelerator/compiler would optimize both of them to `return false`

Comment: The second will be faster since it uses one less token (there's no T_ELSE).  But you're talking microseconds at best.  This is the very definition of a micro-optimization.  Don't worry about it, and write the code that makes the most semantic sense...

Comment: there. is. no. friggin. difference.

Comment: I tried something, and have no clear winner. https://gist.github.com/donquixote/60b7ff69a4f391ddb922a649e7d4cea3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just:

```
return !false;
```

So in real-life example

```
return !$this->isSth();

// Not

if ($this->isSth) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Performance isn't important here - every solution is extremely fast, there is no need for optimization. Remember the words of Donald Knuth:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth. / Quote the greats properly : )

Comment: I didn't want to quote anybody. Anyway... fixed.

Comment: That's what i thought, it's better having a better understandable code for such minimal performance differences. Thanks!

Comment: First rule of optimization: Don't do it. Second rule of optimization (for experts): Don't do it yet.

Comment: This answer works for the specific simplified code example. But in real world we probably want to return something other than true / false, more complex conditions, and more than 2 cases possibly. So the question there is, put an else or omit it? If there is no other criterion, then the only remaining criterion is performance.